# Adding scripts to an iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I am generating an iframe within a jquery dialog box but am having trouble loading some scripts within it.

```
function showDialog() {
       $("#divID").dialog("open");
       $("#modalIframeID").attr("src", "/staff/somepage");
      return false;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divID").dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        modal:true,
        height:500,
        width:960,
        closeOnEscape:true,

    });
});
```

I tried adding them through a load event but havent had any success.

```
function showDialog() {
    $("#modalIframeID").load(function()
    {
        //load scripts here
        $("#addFaci").formToWizard();
    });
    $("#divID").dialog("open");
    $("#modalIframeID").attr("src", "/staff/somepage");

    return false;
 }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Is there any error, or it just isn't doing anything?

Comment: no errors, just not doing anything :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the file that is being loaded into the iframe you could just add the javascript code into that file and attach it to the document ready event.

If not try reading this following article and see if it will help you out :)

http://huuah.com/jquery-and-iframe-manipulation/

Comment: this was the first thing i tried, however i got no results (or errors in firebug) with this and turned to the load event as a possible solution.